# Uso corretto di elisione e troncamento

Tags: orthography, apocope

In frasi come:

- quale è la tua auto?
- quale è il tuo camion?

la parola "quale" viene usualmente troncata, dando "qual è" al posto di "quale è".

Supponevo si trattasse di elisione (ergo "qual'è la tua auto") ma sono stato corretto perché si dovrebbe usare piuttosto il troncamento ("qual è la tua auto").

In che casi si usa il troncamento? In quali l'elisione?

Comment: Per favore usa sempre [i tags inglesi](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-language-should-we-use-for-tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partendo dal concetto più semplice:

**Elisione:** si usa quando una parola di genere femminile termina con la stessa vocale con cui la parola successiva inizia. Ad esempio, "buona amica", può diventare "buon'amica" (o, per fare un esempio più comune, "una amica" diventa "un'amica"). Ciò però **non** succede nel genere maschile, in quanto molti aggettivi esistono anche in forma troncata (è corretto scrivere sia "buono" che "buon"). Di conseguenza, "buon'amico" è scorretto (riprendendo l'esempio precedente, scrivere "un'amico" è scorretto perché abbiamo anche l'articolo indeterminativo "un" oltre che "uno").

**Troncamento:** si ha a condizione che l'aggettivo abbia come ultima consonante l, m (raro), n o r, e che l'aggettivo sia al singolare. Viene usato anche con le forme del verbo essere, non saprei dire se per tradizione o perché "e" ed "è" non sono tecnicamente la stessa lettera (e quindi non è possibile applicare l'elisione).

Da qui segue che "qual è" è la forma corretta perché soddisfa queste condizioni.

Comment: mi piace l'ipotesi per cui le parole "quale è" non possano dar luogo ad una elisione in quanto le lettere "e" ed "è" sono di fatto vocali differenti

Comment: Sarebbe utile se questa risposta contenesse qualche esempio di troncamento di aggettivi davanti a sostantivi femminili. Sono il caso più sfuggente.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Me ne viene in mente solo uno per ora: suor Angelica :P

Comment: Che però non è un aggettivo...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Ah avevo letto male scusa. Forse sto capendo male, ma nell'esempio che fai tu non andrebbe sempre usata l'elisione?

Comment: Un esempio che mi è venuto in mente ora è *una tal bellezza*.

Answer (score 0):

In italiano esite di per sé "qual", quindi, per dire la frase si usa "qual è". 
Si tronca davanti a parole che cominciano per vocale, spec. davanti alle forme del v. essere, e anche davanti a parole che cominciano per consonante spec. in alcune espressioni entrate nel linguaggio comune: qual è; qual era; qual sono; per la qual cosa; in un certoqual modo. ATTENZIONE: poiché si tratta di troncamento e non di elisione, non si apostrofa mai: qual è e non qual'è.

Comment: Così hai solo parafrasato quello che dice già Federico. Hai qualcosa da rispondere alla sua domanda?

Comment: `Si tronca davanti a parole che cominciano per vocale` Non è propriamente corretto. Se così fosse dovremmo scrivere "un altra" invece che "un'altra".

Comment: "si tronca davanti a parole che cominciano per vocale" solo per "qual" in questo caso!